# Converting currencies using JAVASCRIPT. can't set the value of converted input text field through my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, converters

I am trying to make a currency converter using html and javascript **(without jquery)**. I have tried a lot of things but I can't set the value of the text field to the converted amount. What is going wrong with my code?

So what I am trying to do is basically check what currency my initial amount is, based on that call the right function to do the calculations and then **set the value** of the input field with **id="cur2"** to the result of those calculations. I have tried to do that with **the following javascript code**. I am only giving you the function for euro to other currencies (the rest work similarly):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnConvert").addEventListener("click", convert);
}

function convert() {
    var select = document.getElementById("currency1");
    var curr = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var val = document.getElementById("cur2").value;
    if (curr == "EUR") {
        val = EURtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "USD") {
        val = USDtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "GBP") {
        val = GBPtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "AUD") {
        val = AUDtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "JPY") {
        val = JPYtoOther();
    }
}

function EURtoOther() {
    var select = document.getElementById("currency2");
    var curr = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var initval = document.getElementById("cur1").value;
    if (curr == "EUR") {
        return initval * 1.0;
    }
    if (curr == "USD") {
        return initval * 1.13;
    }
    if (curr == "GBP") {
        return initval * 0.79;
    }
    if (curr == "AUD") {
        return initval * 1.55;
    }
    if (curr == "JPY") {
        return initval * 123.27;
    }
}
```

```html
    <select id="currency1">
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
        <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" id="cur1">
    <button id="btnConvert">Convert</button>
    <select id="currency2">
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
        <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="cur2">
```

Not working and I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the value of second textbox. Use

```
document.getElementById("cur2").value = val;
```

to set the value of second textbox

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnConvert").addEventListener("click", convert);
}

function convert() {
    var select = document.getElementById("currency1");
    var curr = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var val = document.getElementById("cur2").value;
    if (curr == "EUR") {
        val = EURtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "USD") {
//        val = USDtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "GBP") {
//        val = GBPtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "AUD") {
//        val = AUDtoOther();
    }
    if (curr == "JPY") {
//        val = JPYtoOther();
    }
  document.getElementById("cur2").value = val;
}

function EURtoOther() {
    var select = document.getElementById("currency2");
    var curr = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var initval = document.getElementById("cur1").value;
    if (curr == "EUR") {
        return initval * 1.0;
    }
    if (curr == "USD") {
        return initval * 1.13;
    }
    if (curr == "GBP") {
        return initval * 0.79;
    }
    if (curr == "AUD") {
        return initval * 1.55;
    }
    if (curr == "JPY") {
        return initval * 123.27;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="currency1">
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
        <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" id="cur1">
    <button id="btnConvert">Convert</button>
    <select id="currency2">
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
        <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="cur2">
```

Comment: you're right... can't believe my mind was stuck to something so simple! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `document.getElementById().value = val;`. `val` is not reffering to that element, it is just a value so you need to set it after.

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/aphxcpcs/